# Identifying subject/domain of a given word

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

My project is to extract keywords from a given text and tell to which domain that keyword belongs to. For example if the keyword is deadlock it should tell the keyword belongs to operating system. I have done till extracting the keywords part. But I am new to machine learning and I need to know "how to tell the domain/subject of that keyword.". Domains include os, networks, dbms... (computer science eng related terms..).

Comment: I strongly suggest you supply us with two important things. The code that isn't working (relevant pieces of code please) and a set of good example data to work with.

Comment: 1.I dont have any code with me.I dnt know how to start with.2.example:if the keywords are (syncronization,deadlock,ethernet,lan,entity,kernel),then my result should be(os,os,network,network,dbms,os).i.e if the word is syncronization then my code should tell me that it is an os related word.Similarly other words respectively.

Comment: Yea this is going to be a to broad of a question to solve for you. If you haven't started to design your own code base we can't help you. We're here to help you solve programming problems - that is those questions where you have a piece of code, but you're stuck on a particular error message that you can't solve. Also what's to say that `ethernet` isn't part of the OS? My OS has ethernet drivers and protocols.

Comment: I am asking about an idea of how to do it.And i have seen many instances where this site not just  helps people who have stuck with a piece of code or error message.And i referred ethernet in network's context.